# Can't deserialize JSON in Unity 5.4 using JsonUtility. Child collection is always empty

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

The Model

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class GetPeopleResult
{
    public List<Person> people { get; set; }
    public GetPeopleResult()
    {
       this.people = new List<People>();
    }

    public static GetPeopleResult CreateFromJSON(string jsonString)
    {
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<GetPeopleResult>(jsonString);
    }

}
[System.Serializable]
public class Person
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string displayImageUrl { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {

    }
    public static Person CreateFromJSON(string jsonString)
    {
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<Person>(jsonString);
    }
}
```

The JSON

```
{
    "people":
    [{
        "id":1,"name":"John Smith",
        "email":"jsmith@acme.com",
        "displayImageUrl":"http://example.com/"
    }]
 }
```

The Code

```
string json = GetPeopleJson(); //This works
GetPeopleResult result = JsonUtility.FromJson<GetPeopleResult>(json);
```

After the call to FromJson, **result** is not null, but the **people** collection is always empty.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> After the call to FromJson, result is not null, but the people
>   collection is always empty.

That's because Unity does not support property getter and setter. Remove the `{ get; set; }` from all the classes you want to serialize and that should fix your empty collection.

Also, `this.people = new List<People>();` should be `this.people = new List<Person>();`

```
[System.Serializable]
public class GetPeopleResult
{
    public List<Person> people;
    public GetPeopleResult()
    {
       this.people = new List<People>();
    }

    public static GetPeopleResult CreateFromJSON(string jsonString)
    {
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<GetPeopleResult>(jsonString);
    }

}
[System.Serializable]
public class Person
{
    public long id;
    public string name;
    public string email;
    public string displayImageUrl;

    public Person()
    {

    }
    public static Person CreateFromJSON(string jsonString)
    {
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<Person>(jsonString);
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about the `{ get; set; }` "limitation" in Unity. That fixed the issue.

As for the  `new List<Person>();` thing, that was just me misrenaming the variables to make the question more user friendly on StackOverlflow.

Thanks